# Running mule application in MuleStudio

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

While running mule application in MuleStudio, I see 2 options.

```
Run As > Mule Application
Run As > Mule Application with Maven
```

I always used first option which worked fine, until a point of time when I defined maven  filter. Using the first option the filters were not getting resolved, so I tried to run using second option which resulted in the following error --

[12:04:57] Starting build...
***Error: Could not find or load main class local***

I created a test project for sharing this problem and uploaded it on github https://github.com/hshira/mule-mvn-filter

pom.xml > https://github.com/hshira/mule-mvn-filter/blob/master/pom.xml

Please suggest me, what is the right way to resolve filters in MuleStudio.

*FYI ... the filtered property is resolved correctly if I build on terminal using mvn command*

Answer (score 0):

it could be issue with maven setup on your local machine.